# Binding TabControl ItemsSource to Collection of ViewModels

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, tabcontrol

For some reason I am having a heck of a time getting my `TabControl` to display properly when binding the `ItemsSource` to a `ObservableCollection` of view models. I'm basing my design off of the tutorial found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx. I did find a few questions like mine here but none addressed my particular situation.
This is my `TabControl` in xaml.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding ActiveWorkspaceIndex}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"/>
```

Where `ClosableTabItemTemplate` is the following.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItemTemplate">
        <DockPanel Width="120">
          <Button 
              Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
              Content="X"
              Cursor="Hand"
              DockPanel.Dock="Right"
              Focusable="False"
              FontFamily="Courier" 
              FontSize="9"
              FontWeight="Bold"  
              Margin="0,1,0,0"
              Padding="0"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
              Width="16" Height="16" 
              />
          <ContentPresenter 
              Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
              />
        </DockPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
```

`Workspaces` is the `ObservableCollection` of view models. `ActiveWorkspaceIndex` is just the active workspace index that I keep track of in the view model. I associate my view model with an instance of a view through the following data template in my App.xaml file.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModelStartPage}">
     <v:ViewStartPage/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

I only add one view model to my collection of workspaces. I see 2 views display in the tab control and they aren't tabbed. It's almost like the TabControl doesnt know to treat the different views as TabItems, its behaving more like a stack panel, stacking the views. If I create the tab items in code it works fine like this:

```
System.Windows.Controls.TabItem i = new System.Windows.Controls.TabItem();
i.Content = new Views.ViewStartPage();
i.Header = "A Tab Item";
this.xTabControl.Items.Add(i);
```

I must be missing some content template or something. I will be styling my tabs later but for now I would be happy just getting the basic tabs working. Also the views in the tab contents may be different for each tab so I can't use the simple textblock TabControl template examples I see all over the place...
I.e. not this...

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock
           Text="{Binding Content}" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried your code in a test project, and the TabControl works as expected here. Could you post an image of the "stacking" TabControl?

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try. I ended up using a ContentControl with a TabControl data template. This seemed to fix things. Honestly I'm not experienced enough to explain why this changed things but it is working now. I'll post my working code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using a `ContentControl` with a `TabControl` data template (like the original tutorial project). Here is the xaml code I ended up with. I did not change the code-behind from the original sample project to make this work. The `ContentControl` is in my MainWindow.xaml and the other two pieces of code were in a `ResourceDictionary`.

```
<!-- Workspaces Tab Control -->
      <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}"
                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}"/>

<!-- Workspaces Template -->
  <DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
    <TabControl Style="{StaticResource ClosableTabControl}"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspaceTabItemTemplate}"
                Margin="1"/>
  </DataTemplate>


<!-- Workspace Tab Item Template -->
  <DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspaceTabItemTemplate">
    <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
      <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Margin="3" 
                        Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}"/>
          </Style>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
      </ContentPresenter>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
```