# WPF MVVM: Binding a different ViewModel to each TabItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a main window with a tab control containing 2 `tabItem`s:

[image: Main Window]

I currently have 1 `ViewModel` which services Tab1 & Tab2. This `ViewModel` is becoming a little bloated with blurred SOC. I want to split the logic into 2 viewmodels: ViewModel 1 & ViewModel2. My understanding is that you can set the Main Window `DataContext` to a Base ViewModel which holds a collection of ViewModels & then you can assert each TabItem to a different ViewModel.

The example's I've seen of these base ViewModels expose an ObservableCOllection like so:

```
private ObservableCollection<ViewModel1> _viewModelCollection
Public Observable Collection<ViewModel1> ViewModelCollection
{
   get { return _viewModelCollection; }
   set
     {
        _viewModelCollection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ViewModelCollection");
     }
}

public BaseViewModel()
{
  ViewModelCollection = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel1>();
  ViewModelCollection.Add(new ViewModel1(Tab1);
  ViewModelCollection.Add(new ViewModel1(Tab2);
}
```

But how do I assign a different ViewModel to each TabItem? I would want Tab1= ViewModel1 & Tab2=ViewModel2?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a definitive best practice for this.  It doesn't do you much good to bind the `ItemsSource` of the `TabControl` to your `ViewModelCollection`, as there is no common 'template' (each tab presumably has its own view).  If you have a fixed number of tabs, I would simply bind the `DataContext` of each tab to the corresponding view model and set each tab's content to the appropriate view.  If the tabs are dynamic, things become trickier.

Comment: Did you try search? [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14009074/1997232), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12432062/1997232), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17952321/1997232) ...

Comment: @Sinatr yes I have read those questions. I want to bind to different ViewModels not a collection of difference instances of the same ViewModel...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class MainViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<object> _children;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _children = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        _children.Add(new Tab1ViewModel());
        _children.Add(new Tab2ViewModel());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<object> Children { get { return _children; } }
}
```

Now in XAML bind the Children to ItemsSource. It will generate each Tab for every viewmodel we have added into the observable collection

```
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"/>
```

Comment: This code snippet is an exact copy of Jakob’s above.

Comment: This may be a copy of Jakob's code, but this answer is more complete. It's strongly typed (not using `object` or `Children[x]`), and actually shows the OP how to do what he wanted to do. This should be the accepted answer IMO.

Answer (score 39):

You can indeed add the view models for your tabs to a main view model.  You can then bind to the child view models in the XAML for your tabs.

Say that you have three viewmodels: `MainViewModel`, `Tab1ViewModel`, and `Tab2ViewModel`.  On your `MainViewModel` you keep a collection of your tab viewmodels:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<object> _children;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _children = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        _children.Add(new Tab1ViewModel());
        _children.Add(new Tab2ViewModel());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<object> Children { get { return _children; } }
}
```

After setting the `DataContext` of your main window to your `MainViewModel` you can bind the `DataContext` of your tabs by referencing the `Children` property:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem DataContext="{Binding Children[0]}" x:Name="Tab1" Header="Tab1" >
      <!-- Tab content -->
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem DataContext="{Binding Children[1]}" x:Name="Tab2" Header="Tab2" >
      <!-- Tab content -->
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Brilliant! exactly what I needed, I like the binding to the index in the OC too :)

Answer (score 4):

I use a framework such as Prism, that allows you to define regions and use the `RegionManager`. You can then define a `ContentControl` as the 'ui' for the `TabItem`

Then you can use the `RegionManager.RequestNavigate` to populate a named region with a particular view (and our views import a viewmodel and set their datacontext).

Comment: Yeah, I've had a tinker with Prism. This app is fairly simple though, don't think it's worth setting up the bootstrapper etc. for this.

Comment: I suppose I could try a base model with a ObservableCollection<object>. Add an instance of my different ViewModels to it & then bind the tab items to the respective ViewModel instance in the collection?

Comment: you could bind the items source from your tab control to a list of tabViewModels that will be shown in the UI. The TabVMs could inherrit from a BaseTabVM where all common things are in and eventually, create a data template for each tab view model in the resource of your project so that they can be individually customized. The binding will go in each individual tabVM, you have a list of BaseTabVMs in the main window view model to bind to and all items can be independently used.

Answer (score 1):

No sure why the selected answer is suggesting to use ObservableCollection and create a collection of tabs and then reference them by index.

I find it more clean to do it this way:

MainViewModel
tab1= ConfigViewModel
Tab2 = UserProfileViewModel

in MainViewModel:

```
private ConfigViewModels _configVM;
public ConfigViewModels ConfigVM { get { return _configVM; } }

private UserProfileViewModel _userProfileVM;
public UserProfileViewModel UserProfileVM { get { return _userProfileVM; } }

public MainViewModel(){

_configVM = new ConfigViewModels();
_userProfileVM = new UserProfileViewModel ();
}
```

In th XAML file:

```
<TabControl>
<TabItem DataContext="{Binding ConfigVM }" >
<TabItem DataContext="{Binding UserProfileVM }" >
```

I'm not sure I understand the benefit of doing this through an observable collection.