# Programmatic Navigation in MVVM Single Window Application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm quite new to WPF and MVVM programming, but I am trying to create a WPF app using MVVM as a single-window application.

I followed the steps here: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/ and was able to adapt the examples given for my project. However, I want to programmatically activate the views; how can I do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, First I checked the example in the blogpost. I admit it's one way to do things, but I feel `TabControl` does the same thing albeit in an easy way. If the number of items in your `TabControl` is static you can find the solution here. [WPF MVVM: Binding a different ViewModel to each TabItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218766/wpf-mvvm-binding-a-different-viewmodel-to-each-tabitem)

If it's dynamic `TabControl` you are after you can check out the example here. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/15488/dynamic-tab-control-in-wpf-mvvm.aspx

if you don't understand any of the examples give me a shout and I will try to help.

**Edit 1**

And also `TabControl` has many properties that will help you do things `DockPanel` can't.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Unfortunately I'll have to wait until tomorrow to check this, but if I can remove the tabs from view this will probably solve my issue.