# DataTemplate problems at runtime with TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, tabcontrol

I'm trying to use a view-model-first approach and I've created a view-model for my customized chart control. Now, in my form, I want a `TabControl` that will display a list of XAML-defined charts defined as such:

```
<coll:ArrayList x:Key="ChartListTabs" x:Name="ChartList">
    <VM:MyChartViewModel x:Name="ChartVM_Today" ChartType="Today" ShortName="Today"/>
    <VM:MyChartViewModel x:Name="ChartVM_Week" ChartType="Week" ShortName="This Week"/>
    <VM:MyChartViewModel x:Name="ChartVM_Month" ChartType="Month" ShortName="This Month"/>
    <VM:MyChartViewModel x:Name="ChartVM_Qtr" ChartType="Quarter" ShortName="This Quarter"/>
    <VM:MyChartViewModel x:Name="ChartVM_Year" ChartType="Year" ShortName="This Year"/>
    <VM:MyChartViewModel x:Name="ChartVM_Cust" ChartType="Custom" ShortName="Custom"/>
</coll:ArrayList>
```

Trying to specify data templates for my tab headers and content, I have this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="tab_header">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortName}" FontSize="16" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="tab_content" DataType="{x:Type VM:MyChartViewModel}" >
    <local:MyChartControl/>
</DataTemplate>
```

My `TabControl` is like this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource ChartListTabs}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tab_header}"
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource tab_content}" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <!-- nothing here :) -->
</TabControl>
```

What happens is that the designer shows the tabs correctly and the first tab content (can't switch tabs because they are dynamically created) showing apparently the right view for the first chart, but when I run the application, all tabs show the same, default, uninitialized content (i.e. the same chart control without any properties set). Also, the instance seems to be the same, i.e. changing something on my custom control (e.g. a date box) this shows on all tabs.

It seems to me that the control (view) in the `TabControl` content stays the same (`TabControl` does this, as I've read elsewhere) and should only change `DataContext` when the tab changes, but it clearly doesn't.

---

Notes:

- All my classes are `DependencyObject`s and my collections are `ObservableCollection`s (with the exception of the `ChartListTabs` resource)
- `ShortName` is the view-model property I want to have as tab header text
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009074/binding-tabcontrol-itemssource-to-collection-of-viewmodels) seems related but I can't connect the dots

Comment: Can you please tell me what is there inside your MyChartControl?

Comment: Is it based on the MyChartViewModel or it has it's own data context?

Comment: @Ilan I thought it was obvious that `MyChartViewModel` is the `DataContext` for `MyChartControl`. That's the way MVVM works, is it not?

Comment: @Ilan I think I know what you mean. You don't see the `</TabControl>'. It has nothing in between. I'll edit the code to show it. Thanks for bringing that up (intentionally or not).

Comment: Is the inner tab item control (MyChartControl) binded to any property of supported DataContext?

Comment: @Ilan Definitely! I've even put a `TextBlock` that is bound to the `ChartType` property (see the array of instances I use) for testing purposes. It shows the correct type in the designer, but nothing at runtime. :(

Comment: have you binding expression errors in your output window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While testing Ilan's answer I found out that when a `DataContext` is declared inside the control (i.e. as an instance of some class via a `UserControl.DataContext` tag), it imposes a specific object instance on the control and the ability to databind some other object to it is lost (probably because the WPF run-time uses `SetData` instead of `SetCurrentData`).

The recommended way to "test" your control in the designer is the `d:DataContext` declaration (which works only for the designer).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution used your code inside, please try to check this out.

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TabControTemplatingHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt="clr-namespace:TabControTemplatingHelpAttempt"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <collections:ArrayList x:Key="ChartListTabs" x:Name="ChartList">
        <tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt:MyChartViewModel x:Name="ChartVM_Today" ChartType="Today"   ShortName="Today"/>
        <tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt:MyChartViewModel x:Name="ChartVM_Week" ChartType= "Week"    ShortName="This Week"/>
        <tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt:MyChartViewModel x:Name="ChartVM_Month" ChartType="Month"   ShortName="This Month"/>
        <tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt:MyChartViewModel x:Name="ChartVM_Qtr" ChartType=  "Quarter" ShortName="This Quarter"/>
        <tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt:MyChartViewModel x:Name="ChartVM_Year" ChartType= "Year"    ShortName="This Year"/>
        <tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt:MyChartViewModel x:Name="ChartVM_Cust" ChartType= "Custom"  ShortName="Custom"/>
    </collections:ArrayList>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="{x:Type tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt:MyChartViewModel}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortName}" FontSize="16" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabContent" DataType="{x:Type tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt:MyChartViewModel}" >
        <tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt:MyChartControl Tag="{Binding ChartType}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource ChartListTabs}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabHeader}"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TabContent}" 
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
</Grid></Window>
```

**Converter code**

```
    public class ChartType2BrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var key = (ChartType) value;
        SolidColorBrush brush;
        switch (key)
        {
            case ChartType.Today:
                brush = Brushes.Tomato;
                break;
            case ChartType.Week:
                brush = Brushes.GreenYellow;
                break;
            case ChartType.Month:
                brush = Brushes.Firebrick;
                break;
            case ChartType.Quarter:
                brush = Brushes.Goldenrod;
                break;
            case ChartType.Year:
                brush = Brushes.Teal;
                break;
            case ChartType.Custom:
                brush = Brushes.Blue;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        return brush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Main VM**

```
public class MyChartViewModel:BaseObservableDependencyObject
{
    private ChartType _chartType;
    private string _shortName;

    public ChartType ChartType
    {
        get { return _chartType; }
        set
        {
            _chartType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string ShortName
    {
        get { return _shortName; }
        set
        {
            _shortName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public enum ChartType
{
    Today,
    Week,  
    Month,  
    Quarter,
    Year,  
    Custom,
}
```

**Inner user control XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TabControTemplatingHelpAttempt.MyChartControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt="clr-namespace:TabControTemplatingHelpAttempt">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt:ChartType2BrushConverter x:Key="ChartType2BrushConverterKey" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="UserContentTemplateKey" DataType="{x:Type tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt:MyChartViewModel}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       Fill="{Binding ChartType, Converter={StaticResource ChartType2BrushConverterKey}}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ShortName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ChartType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <Grid.DataContext>
                    <tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt:TabContentDataContext/>
                </Grid.DataContext>
                <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   Fill="{Binding BackgroundBrush}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding }" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserContentTemplateKey}"/>
    <!--<Grid.DataContext>
        <tabControTemplatingHelpAttempt:TabContentDataContext/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       Fill="{Binding BackgroundBrush}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>-->
</Grid>
```

Please keep in attention, that if you comment out the Grid.DataContext tag and comment in the ContentControl tag,  your inner content won't be updated since it doesn't created depending on delivered MyChartViewModel. Elsewhere 
I can't see any problems with your code.

**Inner user control VM**

```
public class TabContentDataContext:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _code;
    private Brush _backgroundBrush;


    public TabContentDataContext()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        var code = GetCode();
        Code = code.ToString();
        BackgroundBrush = code%2 == 0 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Blue;
    }

    public virtual int GetCode()
    {
        return GetHashCode();
    }

    public string Code
    {
        get { return _code; }
        set
        {
            _code = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public Brush BackgroundBrush
    {
        get { return _backgroundBrush; }
        set
        {
            _backgroundBrush = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Observable object code**

```
    /// <summary>
/// implements the INotifyPropertyChanged (.net 4.5)
/// </summary>
public class BaseObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
    {
        var propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser.Body).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Update**

**Base Observable Dependency Object code**

```
    /// <summary>
///  dependency object that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged (.net 4.5)
/// </summary>
public class BaseObservableDependencyObject : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
    {
        var propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser.Body).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: I think the `BaseObservableDependencyObject` code is missing

Comment: It works. I'm slowly bringing it closer to my code to see when/where the problem arises. If you have any suggestions, I'll be happy to try them.

Comment: @Doc I think that the data binding is broken, if so the same object is constructed for each view model item in your collection (ChartListTabs), that's why I asked you if you have some binding expression errors in your output window. Is there any?

Comment: I don't see any binding problems in the container or `TabControl`. There may be a couple of problems inside `MyChartControl`. The strange thing is that in the designer the `TabControl` looks right, but at runtime things are different.

Comment: Found it! Some research is still needed, but the TL;DR is that I was declaring a `DataContext` in `MyChartControl` in XAML (I so that in order to have code completion in XAML and some "preview" in the designer) and it couldn't be overwritten by the binding mechanism. Any pointers are welcome.